# Is the punctuation here correct?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

the following is the result of me translating and then subtitling I am not entirely sure if I should use a comma at the end of the 1st line or even in the second line. but I chose to put it as follows.

> The reason why we eat oil and fats
>
> and the reason we say that one is healthy, and the other is harmful
>
> is that there are two types of Omega, aka fatty acids that the body
>   needs.

the following is more confusing, as it's not clear to me whether I can use a semi colon in the first 2 sentences in place of ", and", then right after that use 
semi colon because it's a list with comma used in one of the ingredients(the last one).

> This subject specifically has shocked me.
>
> I decided to flip the table while drinking a cup of Matcha tea, 
>     and tell you how to fry;
>
> which oil to fry in;
>
> which oils are beneficial and which are harmful;
>
> what to know about your frying oil of choice;
>
> everything about olive oil, butter, ghee, and other types of oil.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you should use the word "reason" twice in your first sentence. It sounds like there are two reasons, when in fact you are pointing to *one* reason for two things. If you abbreviate your sentence, the punctuation should be clearer:

> The reason why we eat oil and fats, and why we say that one is healthy and the other is harmful, is that there are two types of Omega, aka fatty acids, that the body needs.

That is a lot of commas for one sentence, and so you may wish to change the commas acting as parenthesis for actual parenthesis:

> The reason why we eat oil and fats, and why we say that one is healthy and the other is harmful, is that there are two types of Omega (aka fatty acids) that the body needs.

---

Regarding your second sentence and the use of semi-colons - the generally accepted rule is that you should use *commas* in lists *unless the list items themselves contain commas*. (eg: *John, the baker; Simon, the policeman; and Toby, the architect*)

Only the very *last* of your list items uses commas, and so for that reason I would stick with *commas*. Semi-colons are used far less frequently than commas - only use them if you have to. Also, you should begin the last of your list items with "and", even though it contains the word.

Before you begin a list though, your leading sentence should either transition into the first item, or you should use a colon. Your list is not of items that could append the leading sentence, so a colon is suitable:

> This subject specifically has shocked me. I decided to flip the table while drinking a cup of Matcha tea and tell you how to fry: which oil to fry in, which oils are beneficial and which are harmful, what to know about your frying oil of choice, and everything about olive oil, butter, ghee, and other types of oil.